# The package libpam-systemd needs to be reinstalled

Tags: 14.04

Every time I go into the system, I have Red Circle with a line through it up the top of my screen. If I click on that symbol I get a message:

> An error occurred. Please run package manager from the right click menu or run apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: 'Unknown Error: ''(E:The package libpam-systemd needs to be reinstalled, but can't find an archive for it.)' This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

apt-get doesn't seem to run properly either!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try installing synaptic by ubuntu software center. on synaptic u can find your package. try it from there.

Comment: Now software centre wont even start !

Comment: Do I have a bug ?

Comment: it you get errors, very likely. but i dont think i can help you when u just got a error.

Comment: finally !! All sorted for now !

Comment: I finally could download that synaptic software and all good !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of Aptitude, I didn't see that before. All good now, but if I have any problems in the future I will go there.

Answer (score 1):

Aptitude is a high level package manager, that you can use instead of apt.

Open terminal, Crl-Alt-T

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then run

```
sudo aptitude install -f
```

This should find and fix any broken packages and identify any unmet dependencies.