# Can't update ubuntu 14.04 LTS - libpam-systemd reinstall needed

Tags: 14.04, apt

Here is the error:

```
E: The package libpam-systemd needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

When I try to update Ubuntu 14.04, I receive the following pop-up windows:

> Could not initialize the package information
>   An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message: E:The package libpam-systemd needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

[image]

I reviewed the following post:
[The package libpam-systemd needs to be reinstalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493392/the-package-libpam-systemd-needs-to-be-reinstalled)

When I attempted to input `sudo apt-get install aptitude` into Terminal, I received the exact same error message.

Per request, full verbatim results from Terminal: https://paste.ubuntu.com/25399467/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64564/discussion-on-question-by-justin-scott-coe-cant-update-ubuntu-14-04-lts-libpa).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you had the `trusty-updates` repository enabled at some point, which pulled in `libpam-systemd` in version 204-5ubuntu20.14. At a later point that repository was disabled and something damaged the package installation. Now Apt can't find a suitable package archive to reinstall and restore the package.

For a solution I recommend that you

1. re-enable the `trusty-updates` repository in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`),

   [image: Software updates settings]
2. update the list of available packages,

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. perform a package upgrade with the `-f`/`--fix-missing` option:

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f libpam-systemd
   ```

Comment: If all else fails you can also locate missing packages for your distribution on Ubuntu at https://packages.ubuntu.com/